# OpenCV как выводить (искать) контуры на определенной области?

Tags: python, opencv

В идеале считать 2 координаты и по ним построить прямоугольник и искать в нем.
[image]
В Интернетах нашел что-то про ROI и boundingRect но ничего не понял (новичок)

Answer (score 0):

Да, ROI (Region Of Interest) - то, что нужно в данном случае.

В Python можно выбрать рабочую область так (особенность numpy, slice есть ссылка на соответствующую область большой картинки, так что изменения в `imgroi` отразятся и на `img`):

```
imgroi = img[y0:y1, x0:x1]
```

В других языках и при использовании старого импорта `cv` создаётся прямоугольник и регион задаётся с помощью функции

```
SetImageROI(img, rect)
```

После этого большинство операций над картинкой `img` будут работать только внутри этого прямоугольника. По окончании сбросить `ResetImageROI`

Comment: а как считать клик с экрана?

Comment: Это не имеет отношения к данному вопросу. Будете задавать отдельно - укажите, чем пользуетесь для создания интерфейса